# HAML each loop issue

Tags: haml

I have been banging my head against the wall for the last few hours and i can't figure out what the issue is with this haml code. It is probably something simple, but at this point i just can't figure it out. Can someone please let me know what i am doing wrong with this code(attendees_modal.hamlc):

```
%h4
  Attendees
#attendee_modal_close
  %img{src:"/assets/attendee_modal_close.png"}
#attendee_modal_people
- @attendee_list.each do |attendee|
  .attendee_photo
    - attendee.picURL = "/assets/noPhoto.jpeg" if @picURL == "/images/noPhoto.jpeg"
    %img.round(src="#{attendee.picURL}" class="#{attendee.status}" )
    - if attendee.status == "host"
      .agent_mark
  .attendee_name
    = attendee.name
```

I am getting this error when try to load the page:
[stdin]:7:26: error: unexpected |
  @attendee_list.each do |attendee|
                                      ^

Thank you in advance for helping me with this and stopping me from throwing my laptop out the window :)

Comment: The file extension is `hamlc` – is this a Haml-coffee file? If so it looks like you are trying to use Ruby syntax when you need to be using coffeescript syntax.

Comment: you rock! i was using a each when i was supposed to be using a for. Please list this as an answer and I will mark it correct